# Retrieve LocalAppData with specific program & assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, settings, user-config

How can I retrieve this path programmatically?

```
C:\Users\Koen\AppData\Local\vanlooverenkoen\MIDIMACRO.exe_Url_04ecy2myca3ul5300zb1jbkbmpknlbzv\3.0.0.0
```

This is my path that is used by the WPF `user.config`. I need to get this file after an update to restore the user settings.

When I try this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

I only get this path:

```
C:\Users\Koen\AppData\Local
```

And because there is a unique string after my application name there is no way to hardcode this.

So my question is how do I get the complete path of the WPF `user.config`?

Comment: Why not just use the [`Upgrade()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx) method?

Comment: because not all the values need to be transfered, only 5 of the 25 settings